# postgres Query optimization merge index

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am experienced in fine tuning in oracle, but in postgres I am unable to improve performance.
Problem statement: I need to aggregate rows out of one postgres table - that has large no.of columns (110) and 175 million rows for a month range. The query other than aggregation has a very simple where clause :

```
where time between '2019-03-15' and '2019-04-15'   
 and org_name in ('xxx','yyy'.. 15 elements)
```

There are individutal btree indexes on table for each "time" idx_time column and "org_name" idx_org_name but not composite index.

I tried creating new index with ('org_name','time') but my manager does not want to change anything.
How can I make it run faster? It takes 15 minutes now (in case of smaller set of org_name it takes 6 minutes ). Most time is spent on data access from table.

Is parallel execution possible?

thanks, Jay

QUERY EXPLAIN ANALYZE :

[image]

Comment: Postgres does not support query hints. Anything that can be done will involve creating indexes or other kinds of schema changes (introduction of partitioning, etc). If it is a business requirement that no additional indexes can be added, nothing can be done. FWIW, I don't think PG is actually loading all 175M rows based on your description; posting the output of an EXPLAIN ANALYZE would greatly clarify things.

Comment: You should show us the EXPLAIN ANALYZE (and the query itself, although without listing 175 columns from the select list), not your interpretation of it.    Joins happen between tables (or relations), so it doesn't make sense for there to be a merge join in a query with only one relation.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: I have added explain analyze, changed the content of OP itself, removing my ideas.